# Is there a search API for Yandex, preferably in python?

Tags: python, search-engine

Is there an official API or semi-professional API to make searches on Yandex.com?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's the official API - [this one](http://help.yandex.ru/xml/?id=396706), with documentation in Russian (though Google Translate should probably be enough for most needs). The API is XML-based (HTTP POST requests with XML content, [schema available here](http://xml.yandex.ru/request.xs)), so it's language agnostic.

Answer (score 2):

Since Yandex disabled API access there is no possibility to get search results *official way*.

But there are lot of third party APIs, for example:

- [serpapi.com](https://serpapi.com/)
- [zenserp.com](https://zenserp.com/)
- [serpsbot.com](https://serpsbot.com/)

All of them are paid but have some free-trial searches.

Answer (score 1):

https://yandex.com/dev/xml/doc/dg/concepts/about.html
Since it's XML-based, any language will do.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32015743)

Comment: @burhan the, question is asking for an official link to the API, this link to it with a small amount of explanation is a full answer.  It isn't that the link contains the answer, the link IS the answer in this case.